# Cannot access a disposed object. in c# client & Server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

### I had fix my Problem Cannot access a disposed object. in c# client & Server

Following Points I Used.

- Used Using for Scope Limitation
- i am not Closed Socket Object

class Client
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client Chat";
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];// data buffer for incoming data
            string data = null;

```
        // connect to a Remote device
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote end point for the socket
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 95);
            using (Socket Socketsender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                Socketsender.Connect(ipEndPoint);


                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tSocket Connecting To Java Server...." + Socketsender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());                                   

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\n\tClient::");
                    string theMessage = Console.ReadLine();
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(theMessage);
                    // Send the data through the socket


                    int bytesSent = Socketsender.Send(msg);
                    //Recieved from Java Server Message
                    int bytesRec = Socketsender.Receive(bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tJava Server Says:: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));              

                }
                //Socketsender.Close();

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You create your Socket handler object outside the loop and close it inside the loop. The second pass through your loop you are looking at a Socket object that you have already closed.
Don't close your Socket until you are finished with it.

Comment: I go though you suggestion but i am having same Problem and Client Says  An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: Show the code after this fix. The code in the question now still shows the problem I described.

Comment: i created Socket handler object outside the loop and close it inside the loop and Socket Object i m Not Closed yet..But i had same Problem Again

Comment: When you call Close() on your socket it disposes of resources it is using. You are calling Close() in your loop and then on the next iteration you are trying to use the same socket. You can't use it after you have closed it.

Comment: Thanks Sir Finally my Code is SuccessFully Work